# Joomla's template override and security

Tags: php, security, joomla, joomla2.5

So whenever you need to make a change to a component, module, etc you're supposed to use an override so that it won't be altered on future core updates.

Could those overrides be a security risk as the base code is now older as you update the core?  I've never seen any mention of updating the overrides with new updates.

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't a security risk. All the overrides do are call the HTML or CSS from another location. Overrides are only needed for styling and aren't used for PHP or Javascript functions.

Quote: *I've never seen any mention of updating the overrides with new updates.*

That's because they aren't supposed to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Overrides were thought to change the way an extension is displayed, however it would be a security risk to rely on this and think that no other code can be there (I've seen some "bad practices" in different extensions), you should check the updates every time a release is made.

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is pay attention to the updates, especially the specified security updates which are always marked separately in the releases (and have their own feed etc) and if you see a layout you have overridden getting fixed then check yours. The one thing that might be involved in a layout security is that output filtering was missed, so if you have been careful in your layouts then you'll be okay.  It' baseline essential to be subscribed to the security feed if you are using Joomla.